# Tests using database are failing since spring boot 2.5.x with spring.main.lazy-initialization: true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

We use to run our tests with `spring.main.lazy-initialization: true` on our spring boot 2.4.x application

Since Spring Boot 2.5.x, with `spring.main.lazy-initialization: true` and `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true`, all tests relying on some data from the databases are failing.

When I set `spring.main.lazy-initialization: true`, everything go back to normal.

When I run the tests, the database model is inferred from the Entities and the data are loaded from a data.sql file. When I run the API normally, there is not issue, with or without lazy-initialization

As a fallback solution, we an always set `spring.main.lazy-initialization: true` but I would like to understand why since 2.5.x we can't use the lazy initialization in tests anymore?

Comment: Did you have a look at the release notes? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#sql-script-datasource-initialization There are some changes to how dependencies between data sources and their initializers are handled. It may e.g. be that you need to put a `@DependsOnDatabaseInitialization` on some beans. Without more details, it's hard to say. Which concrete initializer fails to execute in your tests?